# What can offset my form from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am fairly new to programming and I'm creating a form that transitions, yet border:none is not making one of my forms disappear as it should. I feel the code is being overwritten by something. In Jsfiddle it works fine,yet on my browser (http://www.entrilab.com/)it doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: to be fair, the page isn't actually generating errors ;) but that's part of the problem!

Comment: @PeeHaa my apologies. The pages are not transitioning is what I mean

Comment: @danwellman Tell me about it. Why do you think that is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling jQuery methods from `sliding_form.js`, you should include jQuery *before* it. Also, `sliding_form.js` is not actually loading. I assume it's in the `js` directory like jQuery so the path that points to it will need to be correct for it to be loaded...

Comment: Is it possible the script itself could be failing??

Comment: It could be possible, but the script isn't being loaded. Fix this and see if it works

Comment: the `sliding_form.js` file that the demo page links to appears to be empty. How about posting your code here so we can see what you;re trying to do?

Comment: if you check the source you can see exactly what's in the sliding_form.js file. I'm trying to do this --> http://jsfiddle.net/713Marketing/Awh3G/137/ as well as fix the prev transition 4rm confirm to account.